# How can I require arbitrary local script within a webpack app during runtime?

Tags: javascript, webpack, module, webpack-3

I'm trying to load some arbitrary modules during runtime which are not available during build time. Think of plugins which are only required at runtime. So something like:

```
require(plugin_dir + '/plugins.js')
```

needs to be loaded but webpack complains rightfully that this module is not available. How can I make this work?

I tried SystemJS to trick webpack but it figured out what I'm trying to accomplish and fails.

Comment: Looks like I can use https://github.com/ezze/node-require-wrapper to achieve just that. Need more testing to see if it actually works as I expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I used https://github.com/ezze/node-require-wrapper

It works like that:

Webpack config file:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  module: {
      rules: {
          // ...
      },
      noParse: /require-wrapper/
  }
}
```

Then in your code you can use it like this:

```
var nodeRequire = require('require-wrapper');
var helloModulePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'dynamic/hello.js');
```